# set image src using bufferedimage java

Tags: java, html, image, bufferedimage

In Java application, I'm showing text with an image in an HTML report using webview inside a dialog ..

The image is a Pie chart, the following function converts the chart to a bufferedimage:

```
protected static BufferedImage draw(JFreeChart chart, int width, int height)
{
    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width , height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();

    chart.draw(g2, new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, width, height));

    g2.dispose();

    return img;
}
```

I need to show this image in a HTML content by set the src of an image tag to this image:

```
.. <img src='" + draw(..) +"' alt=\"\" height=\"230\" width=\"390\">..
```

and I can't extract a path for that buffered image ..

Before going in this way, I tried to save the image in the system, then set its path in image tag, but the problem was, when the event is handled and the image exported, it appeared in the report for the first time, in the second time the event handeled and the image exported the reports shows the old image !
This is the function that has used in exporting the image:

```
public static void saveToFile(JFreeChart chart, String aFileName, int width, int height, double quality) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        BufferedImage img = draw( chart, width, height );

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(aFileName);

        JPEGImageEncoder encoder2 =

        JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(fos);

        JPEGEncodeParam param2 =

        encoder2.getDefaultJPEGEncodeParam(img);

        param2.setQuality((float) quality, true);

        encoder2.encode(img,param2);

        fos.close();

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the image to file using `ImageIO.write()` and then retrieve the `byte[]` like so:

```
ImageIO.write(bufferedImage,"png",new File("tmpImage.png"));
byte[] imageBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("tmpImage.png"));
```

Then using `Base64.Encoder` you can convert the image to a base64 string that you can pass to the html. Have a look at this:

```
Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();

String encoding = "data:image/png;base64," + encoder.encodeToString(imageBytes);

<img src='" + encoding +"' alt=\"\" height=\"230\" width=\"390\">.
```

You have to add in the `data:image/png;base64,` `String` before the actual encoding.  This tells the browser what kind of data it is looking at

So in your `draw()` method, instead of returning a `BufferedImage` you would just need to return  a `String`.  Base64 is very convient for this type of thing, but does have its downfalls.  When storing base64 images, they are slightly heavier than their actual image counterparts.  Luckily with this implementation, the base64 will never touch your disk.

Comment: An error appears: java.awt.image.DataBufferInt cannot be cast to java.awt.image.DataBufferByte

Comment: @MIBMinion can you write your image to disk for a short period of time?

Comment: @MIBMinion try that out.  It should work for you :) sorry I missed that in your question